# expectation of negative max function

Tags: probability, expected-value

Im struggling with the following:

> Define $Y$ = max(-(X+A), 0) where X and A are random variable, and  $E$[X] > 0 and $E$[A] >= 0
>   How can I prove that $E$[Y] is always smaller or equal to 0?

Thanks in advance,
James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot.

Evidently we have $Y\geq0$ and consequently $\mathbb EY\geq0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot you are right!